# Use script instead of regex for Nginx prox_redirect to modify Location header

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

For Nginx, proxy_redirect, can we use a string instead of string or regex? I have a need to replace multiple occurrences of text in the Location string using proxy_redirect and I am not sure how to do it with regex. Therefore, I am checking if the proxy_redirect can make us of script, then it could be easy.

Comment: You can use several `proxy_redirect` statements in a block, but can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Here is another question that describes overall problem I am trying to solve with proxy_redirect. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647067/nginx-reverse-proxy-location-rewrite/63647448?noredirect=1#comment112550805_63647448

Comment: With single occurrence of text to change in a string, regex works, but with multiple occurrences regex is not possible. And I think if it supports script then it can be done easily.

Comment: How many occurrences of the string are there likely to be? You could write a regex to handle one occurrence, and another to handle two occurrences, etc.

Comment: There are three occurrences as of now. Any hint or reference how to do this is great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple `proxy_redirect` statements within a single block containing the `proxy_pass` statement. Nginx evaluates statements containing regular expressions in order until a match is found, so place the more specific regular expressions before the less specific ones.

To replace a single occurrence of a pattern within the `Location` header of a 3xx response, you would use:

```
proxy_redirect ~^(.*)origin.example.com(.*)$ $1main.example.com$2;
```

To replace two occurrences of the same pattern, you would use:

```
proxy_redirect ~^(.*)origin.example.com(.*)origin.example.com(.*)$ $1main.example.com$2main.example.com$3;
```

To replace one, two or three occurrences of the same pattern, you would use:

```
proxy_redirect ~^(.*)origin.example.com(.*)origin.example.com(.*)origin.example.com(.*)$ $1main.example.com$2main.example.com$3main.example.com$4;
proxy_redirect ~^(.*)origin.example.com(.*)origin.example.com(.*)$ $1main.example.com$2main.example.com$3;
proxy_redirect ~^(.*)origin.example.com(.*)$ $1main.example.com$2;
```

Use `~*` to make the regular expression case-insensitive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for details.

Comment: wow, this works fine. I got an exact idea. Thanks for guiding.